# mypy error for function returning TypeVar based on Type[T] argument

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I have a function that validates variable based on `TypedDict` declaration at runtime. I want it to perform validation, raise exception on error and set return type otherwise.

Essentially, I have this:

```py
T = TypeVar("T")

def validated(data: Any, DataType: Type[T]) -> T:
    validate(data, DataType)  # this raises exception if data is not valid as T
    return data


class MyDataType(TypedDict):
    a: int
    b: str


d = validated(get_data(), MyDataType)
reveal_type(d)
d["a"] + 10
d["b"] + "suffix"
```

After `validated` call variable `d` should be typed as `MyDataType`, `reveal_type(d)` shows it. Hence the last two lines are type-safe. However, `mypy` complains:

```
temp.py:29: note: Revealed type is "temp.MyDataType"
temp.py:30: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("object" and "int")
temp.py:31: error: "object" has no attribute "lower"
```

What am I doing wrong?

### UPD

I f I add explicit typing to `d` (`d: MyDataType = validated(get_data(), MyDataType)`) I get even more mysterious messages:

```
temp.py:28: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "MyDataType", variable has type "MyDataType")
temp.py:33: note: Revealed type is "TypedDict('temp.MyDataType', {'a': builtins.int, 'b': builtins.str})"
```

### UPD 2

Seems like the same issue has already been reported: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/12310

TL;DR: it's not a bug, TypedDict is not valid in this context (although the error message might have been clearer)

#### Software versions

- mypy: 0.950
- python: 3.9.12

Comment: as an aside, you should probably use `object` rather than `Any` in `validated`

Comment: also fwiw, this works if I use `bool` rather than `MyDataType`

Comment: @joel yea, from UPD it seems like mypy can't figure out that `MyDataType` returned from the function is the same type as the one passed to it. with simple types like `str` and `bool` this works as expected

Comment: I'd raise this as an issue on the [python typing github](https://github.com/python/typing/issues)

Comment: thanks! after giving it a bit more thought it does indeed seem like a bug to me

Comment: Shouldn't there be `validate(data, DataType)`? Validating with `TypeVar` looks strange and shouldn't work, no?

Comment: @SUTerliakov thanks for noticing, it's a typo!